# For Loop not executing properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub Find_Max_Yearly_Precip()
    Dim Year_Rng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nyear As Integer
    Dim nL As Integer
    Dim nU As Integer

    For nyear = 0 To nyear = 35
        'See if its the first loop
        If nyear <> 0 Then
            'Decide if its a leap year
            If nyear = 1 Or nyear = 5 Or nyear = 9 Or nyear = 13 _
            Or nyear = 17 Or nyear = 21 Or nyear = 25 Or nyear = 29 _
            Or nyear = 33 Then
                nL = nU + 1
                nU = nL + 366
                Set Year_Rng = Range(Cells(nL, 1), Cells(nU, 1))
                Year_Rng.Select
            Else
                nL = nU + 1
                nU = nL + 365
                Set Year_Rng = Range(Cells(nL, 1), Cells(nU, 1))
                Year_Rng.Select
            End If
        Else
            nL = 2
            nU = 366
            Set Year_Rng = Range(Cells(nL, 1), Cells(nU, 1))
            Year_Rng.Select
        End If

        For Each rng In Year_Rng
            If rng.Offset(, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .Max(Year_Rng.Offset(, 2)) Then
                rng.Offset(, 3).Value = "Max"
            End If
        Next rng
    Next
End Sub
```

And it seems to be not executing the  `For nyear = 0 to nyear = 35` loop.  It properly works for `nyear = 0` but for some reason to goes to `nyear =1` and then ends the sub routine.  Any ideas on why its not working?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding in year values, you could also determine the leapYear by determining if (nYear MODULUS 4 = 1) then it's a leap year.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I have never seen MODULUS before.  How does it work?

Comment: Modulus basically calculates the remainder after a division. So if you had 9 MOD 4, you would get 1 (because the remainder of 9/4 is 1). To use the function in VB, you would use "9 Mod 4". Or in the case of the leap year, you would do If (nYear Mod 4 = 1) then it's a leap year.

Comment: You can do this using worksheet functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do small change in your code:

```
For nyear = 0 To nyear = 35
```

Instead of this line, Use this:

```
For nyear = 0 To 35
```

Comment: Cant believe i didnt see that.  Cheers!